# IBAction for UIButton Causes an unrecognized selector sent to instance error (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I am having trouble using some UIButtons to call actions in my Tab Bar application.

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *callTollFreeButton;
    UIButton *callLocalButton;
    UIButton *emailButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *callTollFreeButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *callLocalButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *emailButton;

-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)callTollFree:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clickEmailButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "ContactViewController.h"

@implementation ContactViewController
@synthesize callLocalButton,callTollFreeButton,emailButton;

-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:7576236600"]];
}

-(IBAction)callTollFree:(id)sender{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:8003334645"]];
}

-(IBAction)clickEmailButton:(id)sender{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:email@email.com?subject=Hello"]];    
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[callLocalButton release];
[callTollFreeButton release];
[emailButton release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

My .m file:

The error message I get is (I get error message for any button clicked, this one is clicking the e-mail button in particular):

```
2011-11-19 18:39:38.786 Miller Tab Bar[761:207] -[UIViewController clickEmailButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b29f40
2011-11-19 18:39:38.790 Miller Tab Bar[761:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController clickEmailButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b29f40'
```

I've tried to connect and reconnect the outlets and actions to the objects on the view controller. Is it possible that it crashes because the SDK can't run test phone calls or e-mails?

I typed 'po 0x6b328d0' into the debugger to find out what the problem object is and it came back as a UIViewController which possibly means that the View Controller is being released before the action is called? What would be causing that?

Thanks.

---

[image: Picture of Interface Builder for ContactViewController.xib]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Nib or storyboard, it looks like your view controller instance is of type UIViewController instead of ContactViewController.

So select the view controller in your Nib (or storyboard), and change its type to ContactViewController.

Of course, if this view controller isn't being loaded from a nib or storyboard, then just check where you create it and make sure you created an instance of the correct class.

Comment: I added a picture of the Interface Builder for the ContactViewController.xib (above) and it appears to be set up correctly (I blurred it out, it doesn't actually look like that haha). Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: I've been using the Interface Builder so the nib is just loaded when I click on a tab bar button. The error happens when I click on emailButton, not when the nib is being loaded.

Comment: No, the problem is when the view controller is created or loaded. You just notice it later when you try to use a button. My guess is the tab bar controller is loading a UIViewController, not this view controller. Where is the UITabBarController? You haven't shown the code or nib for that.

Comment: Yes yes yes. Thank you. I figured it out. I traced it back to the tab bar and found some tweaks that I needed to make in the interface builder regarding that button. Basically, I had the tab bar button loading a separate XIB file instead of building it as a 'view' on the tab bar app's view controller (if that makes sense, that was a convoluted way of explaining it). Anyways, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit bizarre.  I think your viewcontroller isn't being set up properly.

The bizarre part is you shouldn't be able to set the actions if it is not set up properly (File Owner- ContactViewController)

When I send an unrecognized selector to a custom ViewController, it says

-[customViewController foo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2b440

It seems the xib's actual file owner is being instantiated as a UIViewController

Comment: I had this problem. I used `UIViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)` instead of `MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
UIButton *callTollFreeButton;
UIButton *callLocalButton;
UIButton *emailButton;
```

to

```
IBOutlet UIButton *callTollFreeButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *callLocalButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *emailButton;
```

And hook up the `UILabels` to their respective buttons. See if that helps.

Comment: Didn't change anything. I've had it designed this way for a while and previously it worked, so I'm unsure if it's something to do with code outside of the view controller possibly? I've been researching debugging but can't find anything that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Try it on a device, you may have had a point about not being able to on the sim.

Comment: I'm wondering if the unrecognized selector would be "tel:" or "mailto:". I'm gonna keep trying to debug a little deeper and see if it points me in the right direction.

Comment: @MxmastaMills i doubt it, unrecognized selector means you are sending a command to an non existing object, or vice versa.

Comment: I just ran 'po 0x6b328d0' in the debugger and it identified the unrecognized selector as a UIViewController, possibly meaning the View Controller is being released before the action is called?